# Excel - Concatenate Sheet name for cross-worksheet formulas, no vba

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm hoping this is possible. I know it's possible to retrieve the sheet name using REPLACE and Cell("filename"), but what I'm looking for is being able to do the following:

```
=['Some outside worksheet.xlxs']ThisSheetName!A1
```

where "ThisSheetName" is the current worksheet's sheet. I'm doing some tracking, and we track it monthly. Instead of having to create 12 formulas a year, I'd like to be able to use one universal formula for each page.

Is this possible, or will I be stuck using VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
=INDIRECT("'[Some outside worksheet.xlxs]" & RIGHT(CELL("filename"),LEN(CELL("filename"))-FIND("]",CELL("filename"))) & "'!A1")
```

Explanation:

`Indirect` - this will returns the result of a reference to an open file, and this is a key to create a dynamic formula to retrieve value

`CELL("filename")` - this will return the full path of current file, and we need to get the worksheet name only.

Comment: I feel like a dolt because I had been learning about INDIRECT quite a bit, and didn't think to use it for this! I'm upping the answer, and will flag it once I confirm it works tomorrow at work! Thanks!